# Javascript not Running Correctly - Tried Everything

Tags: javascript, html, css

My javascript only has one line of code, and it gets the "getElementById null" error.

```js
document.getElementById("menu-background").style.left = "0";
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <script type="text/javavascript" src="js/main-menu.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu-background">
      <div id="main-menu"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
#menu-background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/background.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  left: 100%;
}
#main-menu {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 1.125em;
  border-color: #b88a00;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

I run visual studio code and have checked the link to the js. I have also tried to run it inside of the HTML file.

Comment: I think you should put your javascript into ```DOMContentLoaded``` event listener of window.

Comment: You can also move the `<script type="text/javavascript" src="js/main-menu.js"></script>` right before the `</body>` (closing body) tag.

Comment: Now my line of js is inside of the event listener. I don't think that worked, but thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Have you checked that you put this into the DOM ready part?

Comment: What do you mean by DOM ready? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Please post the error from the developers console to your answer

Comment: How do I do that? I'm really sorry, I haven't messed around with the console yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("menu-background").style.left = "0";    
});
```

Comment: I've tried that. Doesn't seem to do anything, though. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Could you please share the exact error you have got?

Comment: It just says "document.getElementById(...) is null". Visual studio code doesn't have error messages, I ran it on Codesandbox and it returned that. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/game-y6vsc)

Comment: The problem with the codesandbox. Not the javascript code.

Comment: I found the problem. I posted an answer describing it. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `script` at the end of the document in order for the element to be defined before reaching it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu-background">
      <div id="main-menu"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javavascript" src="js/main-menu.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still isn't running. It's really strange. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The reason the element is null is that the document gets read from top to bottom, this is why the element should be known before reaching the script. Another solution for this problem would be including your code in ``window.onload = function(){//your code here}``

Comment: I know that the document is read from top to bottom, but even with the script link on the bottom, and even with the window.onload it still is not running. Maybe it is my CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem!!!

My HTML file was named "main.html" and when I renamed it to "index.html" it worked!

Thanks for the fast replies, guys. I'm a newcomer here, so I really mean it.